Android camerax - Flash mode not working with OverlayEffect
I'm using camerax version 1.4.0-rc01.
When I'm binding the following UseCaseGroup:
var ucWithEffect = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
   .addUseCase(preview)
   .addUseCase(imageCapture!!)
   .addUseCase(videoCapture!!)
   .setViewPort(viewPort)
   .addEffect(overlayEffect)
   .build()
var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, ucWithEffect)

The flash mode set on imageCapture, does'nt take effect, the flash is always off when taking pictures.
If I'm removing the overlayEffect and bind the following UseCaseGroup:
var ucWithoutEffect = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
   .addUseCase(preview)
   .addUseCase(imageCapture!!)
   .addUseCase(videoCapture!!)
   .setViewPort(viewPort)
   .build()
var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, ucWithoutEffect)

Flash mode is working as expected.
Any suggestion on how to deal with this issue?
